# Using ajaxComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery 1.11.3. I'm trying t use ajaxComplete.It's showing only loading icon without returning error message, only in console. As I've read here:

> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxcomplete.asp
>
> Note: As of jQuery version 1.8, this method should only be attached to document.

But how to use it in my case?

My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#email").change(function() {
    var usr = $("#email").val();
    if (usr.length >= 3) {
      $("#status").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="/images/loader.gif" /> Checking availability...');
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/check_user.php",
        data: "email=" + usr,
        success: function(msg) {
          $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
            if (msg == 'OK') {
              $("#email").removeClass('ErrorField'); // if necessary
              $("#email").addClass("object_ok");
              $(this).html('');
              $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
            } else {
              $("#email").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
              $("#email").addClass("ErrorField");
              $(this).html(msg);
              $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#email").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
      $("#email").addClass("ErrorField");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Try using `$.ajaxComplete` instead of `$(something).ajaxComplete`?

Comment: Kindly do not follow http://w3schools.com.

Comment: And moreover, `alert(not);` is a mistake. There's no `not` variable.

Comment: I just tested it, yes, it should be some string in alert.

Comment: Did you try `$.ajaxComplete`?

Comment: Yes, but it's still the same and in this way, it doesn't show me error msg in console.

Comment: I found out the issue. LoL, you **don't** need to use AJAX Complete inside another AJAX `success` function.

Comment: `$.ajaxComplete` is a global handler, it fires whenever an Ajax request completes, any Ajax request. In other words, it's something that you'd use when you want a handler that fires whenever any Ajax call made by jQuery completes, it's not for use inside an actual Ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't** need to use AJAX Complete inside an AJAX `success` function. Change your code to:

```js
$("#status").html('<img src="/images/loader.gif" /> Checking ...');

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/check_user.php",
  data: "email=" + usr,
  success: function(msg) {
    // Remove this completely
    // $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    if (msg == 'OK') {
      $("#email").removeClass('ErrorField'); 
      $("#email").addClass("object_ok");
      $(this).html('');
      $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("#email").removeClass('object_ok'); 
      $("#email").addClass("ErrorField");
      $(this).html(msg);
      $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
  // And this too.
  // }
});
```

Comment: It's not working, I'm using form for my register form and I'm using this ajaxComplete, too. But now there is no error messageeven in console.

Comment: @mistery_girl I asked you to remove the `ajaxComplete` altogether and check.

Comment: Okay, what are you trying to do? Code looks good! Show me the full code?

Comment: I have register form and I want when user has written email, this email to be checked if there is useer with this email and if there is, error message to be displayed. In this file `check_user.php` I make select to check that and return it.